# RAM usage at CentOS7

Tags: linux, memory, centos-7

I have strange behavior of Linux server. htop\free says what something using 10G of 16G. Reboot helps but only for time. Can somebody explain: what hell is this? I cleared cache\swap. Killed all services. Now i have no ideas. Thanks all for replies.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you running a bunch of docker containers?  If so, this is a [known](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1496204) bug.

Comment: Nope, docker is not installed

Comment: Server used only for postgre and weblogic

Comment: Это пиздец! Сожалею!